# Qt Creator not working with GDB Pretty Printing

Tags: gdb, qt-creator, pretty-print

I'm attempting to use Qt Creator to develop on Unreal Engine 4 in Linux. I've run into an issue with the debugger: I'm unable to get Qt Creator to use GDB's pretty printers.

Epic has written pretty printers for their custom containers (like their string class) and these work great in GDB. From Qt Creator's Debugger Log, I can see that GDB is registering these printers. In fact, I can even enter a "print " command and the output is formatted nicely. However, entering the variable as an expression in the watch window, all I see is the memory address the FString points at.

Specifically, here is the debugger command issued and the resulting output when I add the FString variable "Filename" to the watch window:

Command:

```
140python theDumper.fetchVariables({"autoderef":1,"context":"","displaystringlimit":"100","dyntype":1,"expanded":["local","watch","inspect","local.Filename.Data","local.Filename","return"],"fancy":1,"formats":{},"nativemixed":0,"partialvar":"watch.0","passexceptions":0,"qobjectnames":0,"resultvarname":"","stringcutoff":"10000","token":140,"typeformats":{},"watchers":[{"exp":"46696c656e616d65","iname":"watch.0"}]})
<Rebuild Watchmodel 16 @ 09:05:19.576 [54836ms] >
```

Output:

```
dADJUSTING CHILD EXPECTATION FOR local.Filename
dADJUSTING CHILD EXPECTATION FOR local.Filename.Data


<140python theDumper.fetchVariables({"autoderef":1,"context":"","displaystringlimit":"100","dyntype":1,"expanded":["local","watch","inspect","local.Filename.Data","local.Filename","return"],"fancy":1,"formats":{},"nativemixed":0,"partialvar":"watch.0","passexceptions":0,"qobjectnames":0,"resultvarname":"","stringcutoff":"10000","token":140,"typeformats":{},"watchers":[{"exp":"46696c656e616d65","iname":"watch.0"}]})
>&"python theDumper.fetchVariables({\"autoderef\":1,\"context\":\"\",\"displaystringlimit\":\"100\",\"dyntype\":1,\"expanded\":[\"local\",\"watch\",\"inspect\",\"local.Filename.Data\",\"local.Filename\",\"return\"],\"fancy\":1,\"formats\":{},\"nativemixed\":0,\"partialvar\":\"watch.0\",\"passexceptions\":0,\"qobjectnames\":0,\"resultvarname\":\"\",\"stringcutoff\":\"10000\",\"token\":140,\"typeformats\":{},\"watchers\":[{\"exp\":\"46696c656e616d65\",\"iname\":\"watch.0\"}]})\n"

>~"data=[{iname=\"watch.0\",name=\"0\",numchild=\"0\",valueencoded=\"notaccessible\",value=\"\",},{iname=\"watch.0\",wname=\"46696c656e616d65\",numchild=\"1\",type=\"FString &\",value=\"\",address=\"0x7fffffff76b8\",},],typeinfo=[],partial=\"1\"\n"
>~"\"[{'d_d_ptr': 3, 'cannotBeQObject': 3}, [['locals', 117], ['watches', 837842], ['safePrint', 54]]]\"\n"
>140^done
 <Rebuild Watchmodel 16 @ 09:05:19.576 [54836ms] >
sFinished retrieving data
```

(Not sure if the "ADJUSTING CHILD EXPECTATION FOR" lines were for the previous command or this one)

Toggling the "Load system GDB pretty printers" option doesn't seem to have any effect.

Searching the web hasn't yielded much for me so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: oh this is interesting. I did a diff of the output with pretty printing disabled vs enabled. With it enabled, I get:

<23importPlainDumpers on
sStopped at breakpoint 1 (1) in thread 1.

```
<24-thread-info
>&"importPlainDumpers on\n"
>&"Python Exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'function' object has no attribute 'subprinters': \n"
>&"Error occurred in Python command: 'function' object has no attribute 'subprinters'\n"
>23^error,msg="Error occurred in Python command: 'function' object has no attribute 'subprinters'"
```

Edit 2: Looking into it more, it appears Qt Creator may not support pretty printers that involve using lookup functions. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. It appears Qt Creator expects pretty printers to conform to the structure defined by the PrettyPrinter and SubPrettyPrinter objects, and enforced by the register_pretty_printer() function, defined in gdb's printing.py script and documented here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdb_002eprinting.html

Unreal's printers do not do this.

*However*, even if they did, it *appears* Qt Creator's import code will only import *sub*printers, not parent pretty printers (refer to importPlainDumpers() in gdbbridge.py). It seems the best way to solve this is to update Unreal's printers to follow the examples I can find of using a function to build 'RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter's.